# Is there any way to retrieve both aggregated and non-aggregated values without subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a following table:

**trade_id | stock_code | date | amount**

This table contains all trades I made. And I want to know the number of amount I made in last week and the total amount I have on every stock.

**stock_code | amount_in_lst_week | amount_remaining**

For example:

```
1 | A | 2013-01-01 | 200 
2 | A | 2013-06-25 |-100 
3 | B | 2013-06-25 | 100 
4 | C | 2013-04-01 | 100
```

Today is 2013-06-26 in our local time, so I should get:

```
A |-100 | 100
B | 100 | 100
C | 0   | 100
```

I thought it is not a difficult thing but I wrote a [complex subquery](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/984d4/5) like this:

```
SELECT lst_week.stock_code, 
       lst_week.amount_in_lst_week, 
       total.amount_remaining 
  FROM (SELECT t1.stock_code, 
               SUM(COALESCE(t2.amount, t2.amount, 0)) AS amount_in_lst_week 
          FROM trade t1
     LEFT JOIN trade t2 ON t1.trade_id = t2.trade_id 
                       AND TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(t1.date) <= 7
      GROUP BY t1.stock_code) lst_week,
       (SELECT stock_code, SUM(amount) AS amount_remaining 
          FROM trade
      GROUP BY stock_code) total 
 WHERE lst_week.stock_code = total.stock_code;
```

It works, but I'm wondering whether it is possible to do this **without subquery**? Or any **simpler** way? Thanks.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: I don't think subqueries are bad. I did a little  experiment and while it's not completely scientific I think it helps illustrate http://www.chrislondon.co/joins-vs-subqueries/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
select 
     Stock_code
    ,[1st week] = sum(case when [date] >= getDate()-7 then amount else 0 end)
    ,remainder = sum(amount)
from data
group by Stock_code
```

Answer (score 1):

Most databases support window functions.  You can get what you want as:

```
select stock_code,
       sum(case when date >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 7 then amount_remaining else 0
           end) as amount_in_lst_week, 
       sum(sum(amount_remaining)) over ()
from trade
group by stock_code, amount_in_lst_week ;
```

The exact date/time functions depend on the database.  In SQL Server, for instance, you would use:

```
when date >= cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 7 as date)
```

In Oracle:

```
when date >= trunc(sysdate - 7)
```

MySQL doesn't support window functions, so you have to do it with a join or correlated subquery:

```
select stock_code,
       sum(camount_remaining) as amount_in_lst_week, 
       (select sum(amount_remaining) from trade t)
from trade t
where date >= now() - interval 7 days 
group by stock_code, amount_in_lst_week ;
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
SELECT t.stock_code, 
       Coalesce(t2.amount, 0) AS `amount_in_lst_week`, 
       Sum(t.amount)          AS `amount_remaining` 
FROM   trade t 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT stock_code, 
                         sum(amount) as `amount` 
                  FROM   trade 
                  WHERE  date BETWEEN Date_add(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -7 day) 
                                      AND 
                                      CURRENT_DATE() GROUP BY stock_code) t2 
              ON t2.stock_code = t.stock_code 
GROUP  BY t.stock_code;
```

this has still subquery in it though...

[SQLFiddle sample](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15486/1)